# "Import Spreadsheet" App not available in office365 sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office365apis

Trying to access the "Import Spreadsheet" app from office 365 sharepoint site. I am able to access this app till last friday. But now i am unable to access it. I don't have any changes in my Acces level.'

Please let me know in case of any special permissions required to acess this app.

This is the path i used to access the App.

Site Contents-->Add an app-->Import Spreadsheet

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per permission level you would need at least Edit permission (Add, edit, and delete lists; view, add, update, and delete list items and documents. By default, this permission level is assigned to the Members group) to create a new list, even if it's an imported spreadsheet. All above (Design and Full control) can do the same.

I guess it's a temporary error, which will go away by itself. If not you would have to contact Microsoft support from your tenant Admin Center (https://portal.office.com/support/support.aspx).